# Cannot GET /index.html angular2 quick start javascript

Tags: javascript, npm, angular

http://localhost:3000/index.html
responds:
 Cannot GET /index.html 
[image]

The UI url pops up fine with BrowserSync UI (http://localhost:3001/). 
[image]

I did the quick start for javascript, not typescript or dart.
https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html

Do others get same error just from copy/pasting code and npm commands from this page?

Other threads have solutions that don't apply. 
I have plenty space for installing packages. 
Doubt there's an extra space breaking the app.

Comment: can you show your code. quick start guide works fine for me. any error in your console? are you doing the js one of the typescript one?

Comment: what happens when you do `npm start` in terminal while in the project directory?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the TypeScript version.